Converting dayjs to Date without losing timezone information
I am converting the time and date according to the timezone selected by user. I am facing problem that when I convert dayjs object into JS Date object it loses the timezone information and convert it into local time and date.
dayJs.extend(utcPlugin);
dayJs.extend(timezonePlugin);

dayjs.setDefault(user_selected_time_zone)

dayjs(time_to_convert).tz() // this will convert the date and time according to time zone

dayjs(time_to_convert).tz().toDate() //this will convert the date and time according to local time zone

I want to convert dayjs object to native Date object with the timezone specified by user

So don't convert const convertedTime = dayjs(time_to_convert).tz(user_selected_time_zone); console.log(convertedTime.format()); // Maintain timezone information

Or use UTC const utcTime = dayjs(time_to_convert).tz(user_selected_time_zone).utc().toDate();

Th JS native Date object does not support timezones at all and represents a single moment in time.

"//this will convert the date and time according to local time No it doesn't. It creates a Date with a single value, a time value that represents a moment in time as an offset in milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z (the ECMAScript epoch). From there you can get "local" values (i.e. based on host system settings) using Date get* methods, or create timestamps (i.e. string dates and times) for various timezones using various toString methods or toLocaleString with options. But the Date itself has no notion of timezone, only its offset from the epoch.
